# How to have LogonUser not use cached credentials?

Tags: security, winapi, active-directory, authentication

i am using [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to validate a user's set of domain credentials.

```
LogonUser(accountName, domain, password, 
      LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, ref token);
```

With disturbing results:

```
 LogonType    Current Password                Old password
 ===========  ==============================  ========================
 Network      Succeeds                        Succeeds
 Batch        Fails (0x00000569)              Fails (invalid password)
 Interactive  Succeeds                        Fails (invalid password)
```

Failure codes:

- `0x00000569`: *Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer*
- `0x0000052E`: *Logon failure: Unknown username or password*

Details:

- if the user enters **valid** credentials the function returns `true`.   *(good)*
- if the user enters **invalid** credentials the function returns `false`.   *(good)*
- if the user changes their password, and enters their new **valid** credentials the function returns `true`. *(good)*
- if the user enters **invalid** credentials the function returns `false`.   *(good)*
- if the user enters their **old** credentials the function returns **`true`**.   ***(bad)***

> **Note:** if the user moves to a different machine (one that they've never logged onto before), and enter **old** credentials, `LogonUser` continues to return **true**. This means that the caching is not happening on the local machine - but somehow "*on the network*".

- if the user changes their password **again**, and enters their **new** new credentials, the function returns `true`.   *(good)*
- if the user enters their **old** credentials the function returns **`true`**.    *(bad)*
- if the user enters their ***old* old** credentials the function returns `false`.   *(good)*

How, when calling `LogonUser` can i instruct it to instruct the domain to not use *cached credentials*.

> **Note**: If the user tries to logon to Windows with their old (or *old* old) password, they get invalid password error.

---

> **From MSDN:**
>
> `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK`
>   This logon type is intended for high performance servers to authenticate plaintext passwords. The LogonUser function **does not cache credentials** for this logon type.
>
> `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`
>   This logon type is intended for users who will be interactively using the computer, such as a user being logged on by a [terminal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_terminal_gly) server, remote shell, or similar process. This logon type has the additional expense of **caching logon information for disconnected operations**; therefore, it is **inappropriate for some client/server applications**, such as a mail server.
>
> `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH`
>   This logon type is intended for batch servers, where processes may be executing on behalf of a user without their direct intervention. This type is also for higher performance servers that process many plaintext authentication attempts at a time, such as mail or web servers.

i **am** authenticating plain-text passwords, and so using `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK`. **Interactive** logon caches credentials, which is not permitted here. **Batch**, while undocumented about when it should be used, simply fails.

---

**Update**: The domain only allows:

- the previous password (not any further back)
- only for 60 minutes

It's plain to me that it's a "feature" of Active Directory that's giving a 1 hour grace period.

Except i don't want the grace period, and i don't want to change any settings on the domain (since i don't know any setting on the domain that would allow a one hour grace period of use of your old password).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature of NTLM. You can change the default 60 min. by adding an `OldPasswordAllowedPeriod` DWORD value in minutes to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` key on the domain controller, or you can disable 'Enforce Password History' policy. You might also try using another logon provider like `LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50`.

BTW if you're already providing a GUI, I see no disadvantage using `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`.

Comment: i *am* using `LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50` - i don't *want* to be using depricated NTLM. So to question implicitely becomes, "How can i use Kerberos rather than NTLM authentication?". But the question of *"Why is `LogonUser` using NTLM rather than Kerberos?"* is one that neither StackOverflow [nor ServerFault seem to be able to answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/384719/how-to-ensure-machine-is-kerberos-domain-joined).

Comment: Maybe is because LogonUser is a function from ADVAPI32.dll ( Win32 ) and at that time there is no Kerberos authentication ?!